# Print only directories with more than 31 files

Tags: shell, find

I am using this script to count files on my directory and sub-directories:

```
for i in $(find . -type d) ; do 
  printf "$i %s\t" ;
  ( find $i -type f | wc -l ) ; 
done
```

This script works fine. What I really want it to do is to print only the directories that contain more than 31 files.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c '[ $(find "$1" -type f | wc -l) -gt 31 ]' _ {} \; -print
```

I'd advise using the `-maxdepth` restriction on the second `find`, otherwise you might find some surprising results. The command won't work with names containing newlines.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the line:

```
( find $i -type f | wc -l ) ;
```

With this:

```
FILES=$( find $i -type f | wc -l );
```

Then you could ask for it:

```
if [ "$FILES" -gt 31 ] ; then
```

Comment: i tried this but i am getting an error

Answer (score 2):

This should to it using `-gt`:

```
for i in $(find . -type d) ; do   
  NUM=$( find $i -type f | wc -l );
  if [[ $NUM -gt 31 ]]; then 
        echo "$i $NUM" ;   
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`, to print the paths of directories that contain at least 32 entries other than `.` and `..`:

```
print -rC1 -- **/*(ND/e['()(($#)) $REPLY/*(NDY32[32]oN)'])
```

That's:

- `**/*`: recursive globbing
- `(...)`: glob qualifiers
- `N`: `N`ullglob: don't complain if there's no match
- `D`: `D`otglob: don't skip hidden files
- `/`: restrict to files of type *directory*
- `e['code']`: filter files for which the `e`valuation of `code` returns true.
- `()(($#)) args`: anonymous function that returns true if the number of its arguments is non-zero
- `$REPLY`: the file (here directory) currently being considered in `code`.
- `$REPLY/*`: the files in there. Replace with `$REPLY/**/*` to also count files in subdirs. Add `^/` to the qualifier if you don't want to count files of type *directory*, or `.` to restrict to *regular* files only to the exclusion of any other type of file like your `-type f` would do.
- `Y32`: stop looking after the 32<sup>nd</sup> one has been found:
- `[32]`: select the 32<sup>nd</sup> in that list:
- `oN`: don't bother sorting that list.

Note that the current working directory itself is not considered.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)'s array :

```
x=( * )
((${#x[@]} > 31)) && printf '%s\n' *
```