# How to find all directories with more than x number of files that are larger than a specified size?

Tags: linux, shell, find

How to find all folders in a directory with more than a specified number of files that are larger than a specified size?

One exemplary use-case is finding folders with split movie files which could be [merged](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) like so (`ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i <(for f in ./*.mp4; do echo "file '$PWD/$f'"; done) -c copy output.mp4`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Thanks to](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/167776/233262) @[Muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru) the command, only slightly altered, is:

`find . -type d -exec sh -c '[ $(find "$1" -type f -size +1M | wc -l) -gt 1 ]' _ {} \; -print`

The example finds all folders in the current directory (you can replace the dot for full paths) with 2 or more files that are larger than 1 MB.

Comment: You probably want to limit the depth of the inner `find`'s search to avoid printing the parents of the directories that contain more than _n_ files whose size is greater than _x_. Also, this could be adjusted to handle newlines in file names too. For instance: `find . -type d -exec sh -c '[ "$(find "$1" -path "$1/*" -prune -type f -size +1M -exec sh -c "for file; do echo .; done" innersh \{\} + | wc -l)" -gt 1 ]' outersh {} \; -print`

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`:

```
x=42 size=M+1
print -rC1 -- **/*(NFe['()(($#)) $REPLY/*(N.L${size}Y${x}[$x]oN)'])
```

Would print the directories that contain at least 42 files whose size is strictly greater than 1MiB.

- `**/*`: recursive globbing
- `(...)`: glob qualifiers
- `N`: `N`ullglob: don't complain if there's no match
- `F`: restrict to files of type *directory* that are `F`ull (have at least one entry).
- `e['code']`: filter files for which the `e`valuation of `code` returns true.
- `()(($#)) args`: anonymous function that returns true if the number of its arguments is non-zero
- `$REPLY`: the file (here directory) currently being considered in `code`.
- `$REPLY/*`: the files in there. Replace with `$REPLY/**/*` to also count files in subdirs.
- `.`: restrict to *regular* files (exclude directories, symlinks, fifos, devices...).
- `LM+1`: limits to files whose size rounded up to the next integer number of mebibytes is strictly greater than 1 (files with size 1048577 bytes and above).
- `Y$x`: stop looking after the *x*<sup>th</sup> one has been found as an optimisation.
- `[$x]`: select the *x*<sup>th</sup> in that list (again as an optimisation, so the `code` only needs to check it's passed at least one argument).
- `oN`: don't bother sorting that list.

You can add the `D` qualifier to either or both globs if you also want to consider hidden dirs/files.

But if it's to do something with those files afterwards, you'd likely want to do something like:

```
for dir in **/*(NF); do
  large_files=($dir/*(N.LM+1))
  (( $#large_files >= 42 )) && do-something-with $large_files
done
```

Comment: +1 pure `zsh` poetry!